# Powerdesigner Issues Converting Logical Model to Physical Model

Tags: database-design, sybase, powerdesigner

I have this logical model

[image: Logical Model]

**And I have some domains that I created as helpers**
[image]

I generate a PDM:

[image]

In the table, the columns are associated with a domain, depending on the datatype intended.
[image]

When I get my generated PDM, the domain name is used as the datatype in the SQL
rather than the datatype associated with the domain name.

[image]

In the past when I have used Powerdesigner, this was never an issue with domains.
The PDM did the appropriate substitution of datatype for domain and I had my SQL ready to go.

I'm wondering what particular bell or whistle in Powerdesigner will help me resolve this.

I've been doing trial and error for a few hours now with no luck.

I succeeded accidentally the other day in resolving this but I was just a monkey mashing buttons so I don't recall what I did that worked, but I know it's possible.

My particular issue is not easily searchable in the docs so I'm hoping maybe someone knows what I'm talking about here.

Comment: Please ask 1 question. This isn't clear. Please in code questions give a [mre]. For a UI say exactly how to reconstruct what you're doing. [ask] [help] PS SQL "domain" is a specific thing & not what typically is meant by that term in a DB or ER context, ie a column datatype, and may or may not be what a particular method or tool means. But your question isn't clear about your problem.

Comment: ok. I'll have to figure out how to state this more exactly

Comment: Yes. I figured out that's what I used the other day. The overall answer is that the "Generate Database" is where I need to pay attention. Otherwise the Domain is doing exactly what it is supposed to.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If that Q&A answers this, you can click to agree that this is a duplicate. Otherwise I don't know why you say "Yes" or what you need to "pay attention" to.  I don't know what it is that the '"otherwise" is other than, or what you are trying to say about Domain. Please just edit your post to be clear & complete; comments are for asking for clarifications or corrections.